# How could I remove the central red line

Tags: highpass-filter

[image]
How can I remove the central line; there is someone told me use high-pass filter, is that right? how to use it in matlab

Comment: PLease explain more, what your image shows, how you obtained it and what you mean by "removing the red line".

Comment: Exactly. The red line is a symptom of something, and *why* you want to remove it is pretty critical to *how*

Answer (score 1):

Just apply:

```
[B,A]=butter(3,2*f0/fs,'high');
y=filter(B,A,x);
```

where fs is your sampling frequency, f0=5 (your red band-width, as shown approximatedly in your spectrogram), x is your nx1 column vector data and y is your new filtered data.

A | B is the denominator | numerator of your highpass filter.

Hence the original picture:

```
spectrogram(y);
```

will show the 0-5Hz band in a *pure blue band*, a sign of deleting everything in there...

Best regards....

Comment: Never forget to mark the question as answered :o